# Strange Error in django when I'm trying connect my costum storage!

Tags: django, storage

I'm trying setup costum storege. Looks like all is ok. But there is the next error:

```
 Exception Type:   ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:  

Could not import app.views. Error was: cannot import name FTPStorage

Exception Location:  C:\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 134
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app.views module contains an import statement that attempts to import FTPStorage, but cannot for some reason. You may find [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) useful.